# How to define the timezone and list using lambda in Racket

Tags: racket

I have been given this code:

```
#lang racket

(define-struct utc (sign hours mins))

(define-struct location (city timezone))

(define iqaluit (make-location "Iqaluit" (make-utc '- 5 0)))
(define london (make-location "London" (make-utc '+ 0 0)))
(define moosejaw (make-location "Moose Jaw" (make-utc '- 7 0)))
(define mumbai (make-location "Mumbai" (make-utc '+ 5 30)))
(define nairobi (make-location "Nairobi" (make-utc '+ 3 0)))
(define seoul (make-location "Seoul" (make-utc '+ 9 0)))
(define stjohns (make-location "St. John's" (make-utc '- 3 30)))
(define waterloo (make-location "Waterloo" (make-utc '- 5 0)))
(define winnipeg (make-location "Winnipeg" (make-utc '- 6 0)))
(define bakerisland (make-location "Baker Island" (make-utc '+ 12 0)))
(define sydney (make-location "Sydney" (make-utc '+ 11 0)))

(define participants
  (list iqaluit london moosejaw mumbai nairobi seoul stjohns waterloo winnipeg))
```

I have to define a function `working-group`, which I have defined:

```
(define (working-group lst tz)
  (list (map (lambda (x) (equal? tz (location-timezone (first x))))
             lst)))
```

This function should work like this:

```
(working-group participants (make-utc '- 6 0))
;; -> (list "Iqaluit" "Moose Jaw" "Waterloo" "Winnipeg")
```

I don't know what is wrong with my function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't post images of code; place the actual code in a code block. You should read [ask] and [mcve] to get started asking answerable questions. I have gone ahead and edited the code from your original linked image into your question, this time.

Comment: The question as asked is unclear; you haven't told us what `working-group` is supposed to do. You did show an example of the usage, but it is difficult to say what this means. There is only one `location` with `(utc '- 6 0)` (Winnipeg), so why are other `location`s included in the expected output? You also indicate that your function definition does not work as expected, but you don't explain what output you get, or what is wrong with that output. We can only guess in the absence of clear problem descriptions. Please edit to clarify the question so that someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

`map` will always return as many elements as was given. You are looking for `filter` to do the reduction to the matching locations. eg.

```
(filter odd? '(1 2 3 4)) 
; ==> (1 3)
```

If done right your procedure would return the locations objects. Since you want just `location-city` you should use `map` to transform each element to what you desire. Eg.

```
(map add1 '(1 3))
; ==> (2 4)
```

In your case you are looking for doing `location-city` on a list of location objects. Anyway you chain these:

```
(map add1 (filter odd? lst))
```

Or you can bind the result of filtering to a variable and use that further:

```
(let ((filtered (filter odd? lst)))
   (map add1 filtered))
```

Those do the identical things. One could extracted the stuff as well:

```
(define (odds lst)
  (filter odd? lst))

(define (add1s lst)
  (map add1 lst))

(define (suc-odds lst)
  (add1s (odds lst)))
```

In your case:

```
(define (locations-by-timezone lst tz)
  ...)

(define (location-cities lst)
   ...)

(define (working-group lst tz)
  (let ((filtered (locations-by-timezone lst tz)))
    (locations-cities filtered)))
```

Observations from your attempt:

- In your attempt you are using `first`. That implies either that each element in the list is wrapped in a list (not the case for `participants`). Since using higher order list procedures you should not need to use accessors as you would  when recursing through a list. The reason is that `map` is doing the `cons` and `first` part and not you.
- Wrapping the result of a `map` or `filter` in `list` doesn't seem with. Imagine that you get `("Iqaluit" "Moose Jaw" "Waterloo" "Winnipeg")` from the `map`. Applying `list` to the result will yield `(("Iqaluit" "Moose Jaw" "Waterloo" "Winnipeg")))`, one list with one element being the original result.